# Change property of an object

Tags: c#, windows, object, properties

im just started learning c# and i have this little thing.
i dont really know how to call it but here it goes:

there are like 5 textboxes, and i want to set the value of each textblock with a for loop.
they are called t_1, t_2, t_3 and so on.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)`
{
  ("t_" + i).Text = i;`
}
```

this gives this error:

> Error 1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no
>   extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

while the textboxes do have .Text properties.. what am i missing?
(btw im using MS VSExpress 2012 for windowsphone)

thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

thank you all very much for all the effort! :D
you guys really helped me out, and im back on track learning! :D

Comment: `"t_" + i` is just a string, not your `TextBox`..

Comment: you can't use strings like that as vars names. your form has a controls property that may help you.

Comment: Also, I would use this approach, in this example the code clean every `TextBox` (WinForms): foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox)
  {
    ((TextBox)x).Text = String.Empty;
  }
}

Comment: `var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("t_"))
                                .ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can do that so directly. Create a list of your textboxes like

```
var list = new List<TextBox> { t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5 };
```

and then you will be able to do

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    list[i].Text = i.ToString();
}
```

I also advise you to replace

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
```

so that you can just add new controls without having to change the loop.

**EDIT:**

Sudhakar answer is also a usable solution, but to clarify benefits of my, here are the facts:

- using literals in code is a way to earn a nice bug ... imagine more devs working in the same solution and one of them changing a name of a component so that it better express its purpose
- code readability - `list[i].Text = i;` versus reference boxing and `Find("t_" + i,true)[0]` ... a fairly significant difference in readability

Comment: what about the controls property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: so, i have to place every object (i use textblocks just for try out's sake) in a list?
otherwise i cant access them with code like this?

Comment: That's another option. I'm more inclined to this solution. I don't like to rely on literals in code.

Comment: @user3077955 Yeah, a separate list for each type of control so you don't have to use reference boxing.

Comment: this did actually work! :D thanks, there are only a few typos in it.
TextBlock instead of Textblox
thank you very much

Comment: @OndrejJanacek thank you very much, i was initially more interested in  answer because it looked easier and less work.
thanks very much :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a variable like a value.
Use this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)

{

if (i==1) t_1.Text = i.tostring()

else if (i==2) t_2.Text = i.tostring()

... so on
}
```

Comment: thats a hack lot of code i would need.. i should be able to do it shorter right?
thanks tough :D

Answer (score 0):

The Textboxes are Properties of an overlying object, maybe a ASP.Net WebPage, XAML or WinForm.
To be able to itereate through them you have to look at that object first, and change its structure so that the Textboxes are in an enumerable list.

I would suggest a dictionary with string indexers, probably fits you most.